# how to create dots(scatterplot) on a line in a d3 line chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

my code is working fine, but there is a issue with the first dot on the line. first dot always get the y=2 and x=1 position, but other dots are placed correctly. please help me to place the first dot in correct place.

graph:-[image]

JSON data for the graph:-

```
  var data = [{
            "label": "Execution: 6 - defadmin@gmail.com",
            "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            "y": [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            "xAxisDisplayData": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
          }];
```

here is my code regarding the dot creation,

```
  // Set the ranges
  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, innerwidth]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([innerheight, 0]);

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(datasets[0]['x'], function (d, i) {

     return datasets[0]['x'][i];
  }));
  y.domain([1, d3.max(datasets[0]['y'], function (d, i) {
     return datasets[0]['y'][i];
  })]);

  // Add the scatterplot
  svg.selectAll("dot")
     .data(datasets[0]['x'])
     .enter().append("circle")
     .attr("r", 3.5)
     .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
     return x(datasets[0]['x'][i]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function (d, i) {

     return y(datasets[0]['y'][i]);
  });
```

UPDATE 1: full code

```
                        function createLineChart(data, number) {

                //            var data = [ { label: "Execution 1 - buddhika@gmail.com",
                //                x: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                //                y: [2,1,1,1,1,1] }] ;


                            var widthForSVG;
                            var widthForChart;

                            if ((data[0]['x']).length < 13) {

                                widthForSVG = 1220;
                                widthForChart = 960;

                            } else {


                                widthForSVG = (((data[0]['x']).length - 12) * 80) + 1220;
                                widthForChart = (((data[0]['x']).length - 12) * 80) + 960;

                            }


                            var xy_chart = d3_xy_chart()
                                    .width(widthForChart)
                                    .height(500)
                                    .xlabel("TCS")
                                    .ylabel("STATUS");


                            // creating main svg
                            var svg = d3.select(".lineChartDiv" + number).append("svg")
                                    .datum(data)
                                    .call(xy_chart)
                                    .attr("class", "lineChart" + number)
                                    .attr('width', widthForSVG);


                            function d3_xy_chart() {
                                //1220px  for 12 steps in svg
                                var width = widthForChart,
                                        height = 480,
                                        xlabel = "X Axis Label",
                                        ylabel = "Y Axis Label";


                                function chart(selection, svg) {

                                    var numberNUmber = 0;
                                    selection.each(function (datasets) {
                                        //
                                        // Create the plot.
                                        //


                                        var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                                                innerwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
                                                innerheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


                                        // Set the ranges



                                        var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                                                .range([0, innerwidth])
                                                .domain([d3.min(datasets, function (d) {


                                                    return d3.min(d.x);
                                                }),
                                                    d3.max(datasets, function (d) {

                                                        return d3.max(d.x);
                                                    })]);


                                        var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                                                .range([innerheight, 0])
                                                .domain([d3.min(datasets, function (d) {

                                                    return 1;
                                                }),
                                                    d3.max(datasets, function (d) {
                                                        // d3.max(d.y)
                                                        return 3;
                                                    })]);

                                        var color_scale = d3.scale.category10()
                                                .domain(d3.range(datasets.length));

                                        var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
                                                .scale(x_scale)
                                                .orient("bottom")
                                                .tickFormat(function (d, i) {


                                                    if (d % 1 == 0) {

                                                        return parseInt(datasets[0]['xAxisDisplayData'][i])

                                                    } else {

                                                        return "  "

                                                    }

                                                })
                                                .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function (d) {

                                                    return d3.max(d.x);
                                                }));



                                        var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
                                                .scale(y_scale)
                                                .orient("left")
                                                .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function (d) {

                                                    return d3.max(d.y);
                                                }))
                                                .tickFormat(function (d, i) {


                                                    if (d == "1") {

                                                        return "NOT EXECUTED"

                                                    } else if (d == "2") {

                                                        return "FAILED"

                                                    } else if (d == "3") {

                                                        return "PASSED"

                                                    } else {

                                                        return "  "

                                                    }

                                                });

                                        var x_grid = d3.svg.axis()
                                                .scale(x_scale)
                                                .orient("bottom")
                                                .tickSize(-innerheight)
                                                .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function (d) {
                                                    // d3.max(d.y)
                                                    return d3.max(d.x);
                                                }))
                                                .tickFormat("");

                                        var y_grid = d3.svg.axis()
                                                .scale(y_scale)
                                                .orient("left")
                                                .tickSize(-innerwidth)
                                                .tickFormat("")
                                                .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function (d) {

                                                    return d3.max(d.y);
                                                }));

                                        var draw_line = d3.svg.line()
                                                .interpolate("linear")
                                                .x(function (d) {

                                                    return x_scale(d[0]);
                                                })
                                                .y(function (d) {

                                                    return y_scale(d[1]);
                                                });

                                        var svg = d3.select(this)
                                                .attr("width", width)
                                                .attr("height", height)
                                                .append("g")
                                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + 90 + "," + margin.top + ")");

                                        svg.append("g")
                                                .attr("class", "x grid")
                                                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
                                                .call(x_grid);

                                        svg.append("g")
                                                .attr("class", "y grid")
                                                .call(y_grid);

                                        svg.append("g")
                                                .attr("class", "x axis")
                                                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
                                                .call(x_axis)
                                                .append("text")
                                                .attr("dy", "-.71em")
                                                .attr("x", innerwidth)
                                                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                                .text(xlabel);

                                        svg.append("g")
                                                .attr("class", "y axis")
                                                .call(y_axis)
                                                .append("text")
                                                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                                                .attr("y", 6)
                                                .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                                                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                                .text(ylabel);


                                        var data_lines = svg.selectAll(".d3_xy_chart_line")
                                                .data(datasets.map(function (d) {

                                                    return d3.zip(d.x, d.y);
                                                }))
                                                .enter().append("g")
                                                .attr("class", "d3_xy_chart_line");


                                        data_lines.append("path")
                                                .attr("class", "line")
                                                .attr("d", function (d) {

                                                    return draw_line(d);
                                                })
                                                .attr("stroke", function (_, i) {
                                                    return color_scale(i);
                                                });

                                        data_lines.append("text")
                                                .datum(function (d, i) {
                                                    return {name: datasets[i].label, final: d[d.length - 1]};
                                                })
                                                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                                                    return ( "translate(" + x_scale(d.final[0]) + "," +
                                                    y_scale(d.final[1]) + ")" );
                                                })
                                                .attr("x", 3)
                                                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                                                .attr("fill", function (_, i) {
                                                    return color_scale(i);
                                                })
                                                .text(function (d) {
                                                    return d.name;
                                                });


                                        // Set the ranges
                                        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, innerwidth]);
                                        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([innerheight, 0]);


                                        // Scale the range of the data
                                        x.domain(d3.extent(datasets[0]['x']));
                                        y.domain([1, d3.max(datasets[0]['y'])]);

                                        svg.selectAll("dot")
                                                .data(d3.zip(datasets[0].x, datasets[0].y))
                                                .enter().append("circle")
                                                .attr("r", 3.5)
                                                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                                                    return x(d[0]);
                                                })
                                                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                                                    return y(d[1]);
                                                });



                                    });
                                }

                                chart.width = function (value) {
                                    if (!arguments.length) return width;
                                    width = value;
                                    return chart;
                                };

                                chart.height = function (value) {
                                    if (!arguments.length) return height;
                                    height = value;
                                    return chart;
                                };

                                chart.xlabel = function (value) {
                                    if (!arguments.length) return xlabel;
                                    xlabel = value;
                                    return chart;
                                };

                                chart.ylabel = function (value) {
                                    if (!arguments.length) return ylabel;
                                    ylabel = value;
                                    return chart;
                                };

                                return chart;
                            }


                        }
```

UPDATE 2:

html view of created circles-(check the first circle, it always has cx=0 and cy=0 cordinates.other circles are fine)

[image]

UPDATE 3: feddle

[feddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhfzb3qa/3/)

Comment: for y.domain I'm guessing you want `y.domain([1, 3,`... rather than the max().

Comment: this is not the answer for this question andrew, i am using the dynamic json data, that mean i cant use static max and min values here. here problem is all the dots are created perfectly what is expected way except the first dot. first dot always use y=2 and x=1 coordinates whatever the json data comes with different data values for the first dot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `d3.extent()` as well as `d3.max()` is flawed. The functions provided to these methods are just accessors; there is no parameter `i` for an actual iteration. They are meant as a means to actually access the relevant data of the array, which was passed in as the first parameter. Because you are already passing in the flat data arrays, both accessor function can be reduced to `function (d) { return d; }`. These might further be omitted because this is the default behavior. Your domain setup thus becomes:

```
// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(datasets[0]['x']));
y.domain([1, d3.max(datasets[0]['y'])]);
```

Personally, I would also rewrite your data binding logic to improve readability:

```
// Add the scatterplot
svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(d3.zip(datasets[0].x, datasets[0].y))
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
      return x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return y(d[1]);
    });
```

Instead of doing the cumbersome deep access into the `datasets` array each time you need those values, this uses [`d3.zip()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_zip) to build a new array of arrays containing the points' coordinates, which is then bound to the selection. As you can see, this leaves you with clean code for setting your `cx` and `cy` attribute values.

Besides these technical shortcomings there is a logical glitch in setting up your `y` scale's domain—as indicated by Andrew's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577353/how-to-create-dots-on-a-line-in-a-d3-line-chart/41578163?noredirect=1#comment70360213_41577353)—, where you are doing

```
y.domain([1, d3.max(datasets[0]['y'])]);
```

In the dataset you provided the maximum value for y is 2, though. This way your domain will be set to `[1, 2]` leaving out the `3`. With this domain the point will consequently be drawn at the origin. Because your y values are categories, this is obviously not what you want. To always draw the full range of categories, you could use static values to set up your scale's domain:

```
y.domain([1, 3]);
```

You are already doing it this way—in a rather awkward way, though—for your other scale `y_scale`, which is why the line is drawn correctly.

Of course, you could also decide to only draw the categories contained in the dataset, in which case you would keep the `d3.max()` in the domain, but you will then have to also do the same for your `y_scale`'s domain.

Have a look at the following snippet for a working example. It contains the code from your JSFiddle having just the one line changed, where the `y` scale's domain is set up.

```js
var data = [{
  "label": "Execution: 6 - defadmin@gmail.com",
  "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  "y": [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  "xAxisDisplayData": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
}];

var number = 1;

var widthForSVG;
var widthForChart;

if ((data[0]['x']).length < 13) {

  widthForSVG = 1220;
  widthForChart = 960;

} else {


  widthForSVG = (((data[0]['x']).length - 12) * 80) + 1220;
  widthForChart = (((data[0]['x']).length - 12) * 80) + 960;

}


var xy_chart = d3_xy_chart()
.width(widthForChart)
.height(500)
.xlabel("TCS")
.ylabel("STATUS");


// creating main svg
var svg = d3.select(".lineChartDiv1").append("svg")
.datum(data)
.call(xy_chart)
.attr("class", "lineChartDiv1")
.attr('width', widthForSVG);





function d3_xy_chart() {

  var width = widthForChart,
      height = 480,
      xlabel = "X Axis Label",
      ylabel = "Y Axis Label";


  function chart(selection, svg) {

    var numberNUmber = 0;
    selection.each(function(datasets) {
      //
      // Create the plot.
      //


      var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
          innerwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
          innerheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


      // Set the ranges



      var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, innerwidth])
      .domain([d3.min(datasets, function(d) {


        return d3.min(d.x);
      }),
               d3.max(datasets, function(d) {

                 return d3.max(d.x);
               })
              ]);


      var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([innerheight, 0])
      .domain([d3.min(datasets, function(d) {

        return 1;
      }),
               d3.max(datasets, function(d) {
                 // d3.max(d.y)
                 return 3;
               })
              ]);

      var color_scale = d3.scale.category10()
      .domain(d3.range(datasets.length));

      var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x_scale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickFormat(function(d, i) {


        if (d % 1 == 0) {

          return parseInt(datasets[0]['xAxisDisplayData'][i])

        } else {

          return "  "

        }

      })
      .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function(d) {

        return d3.max(d.x);
      }));



      var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y_scale)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function(d) {

        return d3.max(d.y);
      }))
      .tickFormat(function(d, i) {


        if (d == "1") {

          return "NOT EXECUTED"

        } else if (d == "2") {

          return "FAILED"

        } else if (d == "3") {

          return "PASSED"

        } else {

          return "  "

        }

      });

      var x_grid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x_scale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickSize(-innerheight)
      .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function(d) {
        // d3.max(d.y)
        return d3.max(d.x);
      }))
      .tickFormat("");

      var y_grid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y_scale)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSize(-innerwidth)
      .tickFormat("")
      .ticks(d3.max(datasets, function(d) {

        return d3.max(d.y);
      }));

      var draw_line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("linear")
      .x(function(d) {

        return x_scale(d[0]);
      })
      .y(function(d) {

        return y_scale(d[1]);
      });

      var svg = d3.select(this)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 90 + "," + margin.top + ")");

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
      .call(x_grid);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y grid")
      .call(y_grid);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
      .call(x_axis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("dy", "-.71em")
      .attr("x", innerwidth)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(xlabel);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(y_axis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(ylabel);


      var data_lines = svg.selectAll(".d3_xy_chart_line")
      .data(datasets.map(function(d) {

        return d3.zip(d.x, d.y);
      }))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "d3_xy_chart_line");


      data_lines.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {

        return draw_line(d);
      })
      .attr("stroke", function(_, i) {
        return color_scale(i);
      });

      data_lines.append("text")
      .datum(function(d, i) {
        return {
          name: datasets[i].label,
          final: d[d.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return ("translate(" + x_scale(d.final[0]) + "," +
                y_scale(d.final[1]) + ")");
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("fill", function(_, i) {
        return color_scale(i);
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });


      // Set the ranges
      var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, innerwidth]);
      var y = d3.scale.linear().range([innerheight, 0]);


      // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(datasets[0]['x']));
      y.domain([1, 3]);

      // console.log(JSON.stringify(d3.extent(datasets[0]['x'])))
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(d3.max(datasets[0]['y'])))

      // Add the scatterplot

      svg.selectAll("dot")
      .data(d3.zip(datasets[0].x, datasets[0].y))
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", datasets[0]['label'])
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {

        // console.log(JSON.stringify(d[0])+" XXXXXXXXXXx ")

        return x(d[0]);


      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(d[1])+" YYYYYYYyy ")
        return y(d[1]);
      });



    });
  }

  chart.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.xlabel = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return xlabel;
    xlabel = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.ylabel = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return ylabel;
    ylabel = value;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path,
.grid line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.area {
  fill: lightgray;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}
rect.pane {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="lineChartDiv1" style=" overflow-x: scroll">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you provided answer is one of alternative and best way to do this. same thing happen. still i have that issue. first value always use y=2 and x=1. can you please tell me the reason. if need i will give the other codes also.

Comment: creating line code part and other codes working perfectly, issues only with the dot creation.

Comment: @BuddhikaAlwis What does your *actual* data look like? The first sample you provided (right under the image) actually had an x=1, y= **2**... Are you sure, it starts off with some other value?

Comment: This is the json data for the graph. //            var dataset = [ { label: "Execution 1 - buddhika@gmail.com",
 //                x: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
 //                y: [2,1,1,1,1,1] }] ; but these json data change time to time. Y hats mean it create few graphs witg few aterations

Comment: Yep positive about that. I checked few graphs. All are start with that y=2 and x=1 cordinates.

Comment: First dot's cx and cy values are always (0,0) that is the issue

Comment: @BuddhikaAlwis I am confused right now... What is the expected behavior and what is the error? The image seems to be alright, at least does it correspond to the data you provided. Please set up an executable demo showing the effect. It would be much easier to help if there was some code to fiddle around with.

Comment: expected behaviour is first dot of the graph should place in the "FAILED". not in the "PASSED". in this graph's line start with the "FAILED". but first dot it start with the "PASSED". it is wrong . i need to place the first dot in the FAILED. here first dot hasnt correct coordinates. i cant understand what is the reason for that. json data and circle coordinates are not match.

Comment: still i am interest a answer from you.

Comment: @BuddhikaAlwis Have you seen my update from earlier today? It has an analysis and a solution for your misplaced dots. Please re-read the answer, especially the last part starting at "Besides these technical shortcomings...".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132994/discussion-between-buddhika-alwis-and-altocumulus).

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
           if(data[0]['y'][1]==1){

                document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[0].setAttribute('cx','0');
                document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[0].setAttribute('cy','225');


            }else if(data[0]['y'][1]==2){

                document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[0].setAttribute('cx','0');
                document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[0].setAttribute('cy','450');

            }else{

                document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[0].setAttribute('cx','0');
                document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[0].setAttribute('cy','0');


            }
```

Hey I (Buddhika) improved your code below way, other wise it is useless :

```
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label']);

                            for (var i =0; i<element.length; i++){



                                if(data[0]['y'][0]==1 & data[0]['x'][i]==0){

                                    document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[i].setAttribute('cy','450');


                                }else if(data[0]['y'][0]==2  & data[0]['x'][i]==0){


                                    document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[i].setAttribute('cy','225');

                                }else if(data[0]['y'][0]==3 & data[0]['x'][i]==0){


                                    document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[i].setAttribute('cy','0');


                                }else if(data[0]['y'][i]==1){


                                    document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[i].setAttribute('cy','450');


                                }else if(data[0]['y'][i]==2){


                                    document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[i].setAttribute('cy','225');

                                }else if(data[0]['y'][i]==3){


                                    document.getElementsByClassName(data[0]['label'])[i].setAttribute('cy','0');


                                }

                            }
```